# How to set the background + rounded shape of linear layout at run time

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello I am trying to set the background image on the `LinearLayout`, first I need to make it rounded that I made using `shape` tag and calling `setBackgroundResource` to make it rounded but now how should I set any drawable also at run time on same `LinearLayout`

layout_rounded.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

and I did this

```
linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.layout_rounded);
```

Here to set the background on the `LinearLayout` then I have to call the `setBackgroundDrawable` but after calling this, it set the drawable but again it unset the shape of the `LinearLayout`.

I don't have that drawable in res, that background I am getting from URL then trying to set

Can you please look how to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You set the background in `layout_rounded.xml` itself..

Comment: @Lal I don't have that drawable in `res`, that background I am getting from URL

Comment: First clear one thing to me what you gonna set a `Image` or `rounded_xml`?

Comment: @SimplePlan I want to set it to rounded, plus the bitmap which I am getting from URL that I want to set on the `LinearLayout` as background image

Comment: That is not possible. but another way is you need to convert this Bitmap into rounded corner and set as background to your layout

Comment: See  this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391830/how-to-programmatically-round-corners-and-set-random-background-colors)

Comment: @Lal I'm not looking to set the color, I want to set the bitmap

Comment: Just for curiosity, Why cant you use imagebutton???

Comment: Check my edited answer for that.. @Williams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did this by simply making the bitmap to rounded shape. Now there is no need to give that `LinearLayout` shape to rounded because the bitmap I am setting to the `LinearLayout` is of rounded shape that is making `LinearLayout` shape to rounded.

```
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;

public class RoundedCornersDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {

  private final BitmapShader bitmapShader;
  private final Paint p;
  private final RectF rect;
  private final float borderRadius;

  public RoundedCornersDrawable(final Resources resources, final Bitmap bitmap) {
    super(resources, bitmap);
    bitmapShader = new BitmapShader(getBitmap(), Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    final Bitmap b = getBitmap();
    p = getPaint();
    p.setAntiAlias(true);
    p.setShader(bitmapShader);
    final int w = b.getWidth();
    final int h = b.getHeight();
    rect = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
    borderRadius = 0.15f * Math.min(w, h);
  }

  @Override
  public void draw(final Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, borderRadius, borderRadius, p);
  }
}
```

This is which is helpful for me and worked for what I was looking.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[Shape](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)** in android to make the rounder corners

create the xml file named it as `roundcorner.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid android:color="#33DDFF" />
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    </shape>
```

In your `ImageButton` add this attribute `android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"`

```
<ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
                android:src="@drawable/friends"
                android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:layout_marginRight="62dp" />
```

**OR**

Use image view set `android:src = "your image"` , `android:background= "your shape "`and `android:clickable="true"`

Comment: it is setting the background color using `setColor` that is not I am looking

Comment: there is no method `setBackgrounddrawable` on `GradientDrawable` object, see in the docs

Comment: Sorry..its `setBackgroundDrawable`

Comment: Not available which you are telling

Comment: If that doesnt work..See the answer in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115715/how-do-i-programmatically-set-the-background-color-gradient-on-a-custom-title-ba)

Comment: I'm not looking to do my task using View as `ImageButton`, I want to do using `ViewGroup` as LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. Hope this will help you.

Note that I have used `FrameLayout` here instead of `LinearLayout`, in order to achieve your requirement.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    FrameLayout frame;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
        super.onCreate(paramBundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);
        frame.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.layout_round); // set your rounded background here
        frame.setForeground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)); // set your background image here
    }   
}
```