# Android how to draw Rounded Rectangle shape programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface

I have `TextView` and I want to draw Rounded Rectangle shape programmatically and I want to set that shape as a Background of `TextView`? and I want to change it colors dynamically, I have posted the picture ?

[image]

Comment: check out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391830/how-to-programmatically-round-corners-and-set-random-background-colors)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static void makeRoundCorner(int bgcolor,int radius,View v,int strokeWidth,int strokeColor)
{
    GradientDrawable gdDefault = new GradientDrawable();
    gdDefault.setColor(bgcolor);
    gdDefault.setCornerRadius(radius);
    gdDefault.setStroke(strokeWidth, strokeColor);
    v.setBackgroundDrawable(gdDefault);
}
```

here View v = your textview or button or anything.

Comment: hi i have tried this with these paramenters
makeRoundCorner(Color.RED, 30, valueTV11, 30, Color.RED);
but rounded rect is not creating?

Comment: try this makeRoundCorner(Color.RED, 30, valueTV11, 2, Color.WHITE);