# Android setting background color for textview that has a custom background already

Tags: android, colors, background

I have a custom background for a TextView like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<corners android:radius="45dp"/>

<padding android:bottom="10dp"
         android:left="10dp"
         android:right="10dp"
         android:top="10dp"/>
```

I want to change many color of it dynamically. So I have tried to change background color by:

```
title.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.red));
```

But after i change background color, I can not see the corner of it. How can I change color dynamically for that textview ?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391830/how-to-programmatically-round-corners-and-set-random-background-colors

Comment: thanks, it's working :D

Answer (score 1):

That happens because by using `title.setBackgroundColor()` you are replacing your custom background hence the corners disappear.

Try retrieving the drawable instead and change its color.

```
GradientDrawable titleDrawable = (GradientDrawable) title.getBackground();
titleDrawable.setColor(Color.RED)
```