# When I change the background of a Card view, the corner radius is reset

Tags: android, view, background, android-cardview, cornerradius

The situation is that when I modify a `Card` view background from a program then the corner radius of the `Card` view reset. But why?
*(I don't think I need to provide any other information (code, picture of the result, etc.), because I think it's clear enough to understand. If you need more information then you should write down in a comment.)*

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you try to use CardView with corner radius you will face this problem when you set background color dynamically. Please use `yourCardView.setCardBackgroundColor()` methord instead of  `yourCardView.setBackgroundColor()` :)

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution to the question.
I needed to retrieve the background of the view and set its color, then I assigned the new background to the view.

```
Drawable backgroundOff = v.getBackground(); //v is a view
backgroundOff.setTint(defaultColor); //defaultColor is an int 
v.setBackground(backgroundOff);
```

*(This answer helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18394982/9377499)*

Comment: Works like a charm for instance when you want to change color of every other `CardView` inside a `RecyclerView` and preserve rounded corners. During the process you are only able to access `CardView` elements as `android.view.View` *itemViews*, which have `setBackgroundColor()` method (it fails) but there is no `setCardBackgroundColor()` method available.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem and fix the problem this way

At first, create the shape named in Drawable "shape_background_cardview" and this add below code

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="@color/gray500" />
<corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

step second, set the shape to the background CardView yourself

```
yourCardView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_background_cardview);
```

GoodLuck