# OnTouch Listener removes round corners on CardView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I added `onTouchListener` to my `RecyclerView` adapter and it works fine with changing the color, but it also removes the round corners of `RecyclerView`. You can see it in the screenshot.

Here is the code:

```
holder.cardViewRemaining.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f0f0f0"));
        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
        {
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        return false;
    });
```

[image: before touch]

[image: after touch]

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what the question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `setCardBackgroundColor()` .

```
holder.cardViewRemaining.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            holder.cardViewRemaining.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f0f0f0"));
        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
        {
            holder.cardViewRemaining.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[How to programmatically round corners and set random background colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391830/how-to-programmatically-round-corners-and-set-random-background-colors)

It seems that instead of using `setBackgroundColor` method, you should retrieve the background drawable and set its color.