# Adding inputs to drawables in android to make them dynamic

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I have a drawable `layout_bg.xml` which adds a rounded and colored background to a layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#2B2B2B"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#373737" />
    <corners android:radius="40dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

This works fine but I need this for many many layouts and I need different colors and corner radii.
Of course I could create all different files for different use cases but this solution doesn't scale up for a lot of different variations.

So, Is there a way to input parameters by the layout calling this drawable (similar to how functions work)

I am new to working with android so pardon me if this sounds unreasonable.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391830/how-to-programmatically-round-corners-and-set-random-background-colors

Comment: @CSmith Thanks, It worked! But is there any way to do it declaratively? As it causes a new issue; whenever the fragment containing the layout is loaded, there is a brief flashing of the the original color, before the `drawable.setColor();` is executed in the `onCreateView()` of the fragment as proposed in the solution in that post.

Comment: why not just set initial color to transparent?, or make the entire drawable invisible (alpha=0) until rendered

Comment: Making the drawable invisible wasn't quite working as the contents of the layout were rendered first and then the color suddenly showed up. However, making the whole layout  invisible is working correctly. Thanks for the solution.